# Removing S4 class column in R (flowCore)

Tags: r, r-s4

I work with the package `flowCore` found in [Bioconductor](https://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/flowCore.html), which reads my data files in an S4 class format. You can type `library(flowCore)` and then `data(GvHD)` which loads an example dataset. When you type `GvHD` you can see that this dataset is made out of 35 experiments, which can be accessed individually by typing for example `GvHD[[1]]`.

Now I am trying to delete two columns `FSC-H` and `SSC-H` from **all** the experiments, but I have been unsuccessful.

I have tried `myDataSet<- within(GvHD, rm("FSC-H","SSC-H"))` but it doesn't work. I would greatly appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted my question on the relevant [GitHub page](https://github.com/RGLab/flowCore/issues/184) for `flowCore` and the answer was provided by **Jacob Wagner**.

`GvHD[[1]]` is a `flowFrame`, not a simple data frame, which is why the NULL assignment doesn't work. The underlying representation is also a matrix, which also doesn't support dropping a column by assigning it `NULL`.

If you want to drop columns, here are some ways you could do that. Note for all of these I'm subsetting columns for the whole `flowSet` rather than looping through each `flowFrame`. But you could perform these operations on each `flowFrame` as well.

As Greg mentioned, choose the columns you want to keep:

```
data(GvHD)
all_cols <- colnames(GvHD)
keep_cols <- all_cols[!(all_cols %in% c("FSC-H", "SSC-H"))]
GvHD[,keep_cols]
```

Or you could just filter in the subset:

`GvHD[,!colnames(GvHD) %in% c("FSC-H", "SSC-H")]`

You could also grab the numerical indices you want to drop and then use negative subsetting.

```
# drop_idx <- c(1,2)
drop_idx <- which(colnames(GvHD) %in% c("FSC-H", "SSC-H"))
GvHD[,-drop_idx]
```

Answer (score 0):

`rm` isn't meant for removing columns. The normal procedure is to assign `NULL` to that column:

```
for (i in 1:35){
  GvHD[[i]][,c("FSC-H","SSC-H")] <- NULL
}
```

This is the same as you would do for a data frame.

Comment: I doesn't work. I get the following error ```Error in GvHD[[i]][, c("FSC-H", "SSC-H")] <- NULL : object of type 'S4' is not subsettable```

Comment: you may need to coerce them to data frame using `as.data.frame` in that case — if that doesn't work then it looks like the author of the package did not provide a way to remove columns.